# Lightning Datatable does not properly resize when inside grid (flexbox)

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable, bug, slds-grid

Normally the width of a `<lightning-datatable>` changes dynamically as you change the width of the browser.

**However**,  When I put a `<lightning-datatable>` inside a grid (`<div class="slds-grid">...</div>`, which is basically `display: flex`), there's an issue. The datatable does dynamically expand, but once expanded it keeps it's expanded width and does not contract. You can see this behavior in the screen capture below taken from [this code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/wi4qdAyHtsdMuife4zXj/src/app.html):

[image]

**Does anyone know why this bug is happening and if there's a workaround?**

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Within the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), it mentions `lightning-datatable doesn't fully support containers with display:inline-block or flex properties.`

Comment: I have a handful of screens that have a collapsible right panel. So I'm using a wrapper component that uses `<lightning:layout>`, which of course uses grids (via flexbox). Using grids/flexbox in a layout seems like an extremely basic and common thing for lightning datatable to have a limitation on.